# How to compare two arrays of Json by each of their elements Id?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects with the same structure , each one of them came from database query. How can I map the cross section into a new array by comparing the `ID` value.

```
tempArray=[{city:london,subject:"testdata", id:7777},   {city:london,subject:"testdata", id:5555}]

tempArray1=[{city:london,subject:"testdata", id:8888},   {city:london,subject:"testdata", id:5555}]
```

I am trying to get the result:

```
 newArray=[{city:london,subject:"testdata", id:5555}]
```

This is my try but I failed miserably:

```
 let newArray=tempArray.map((x)=>{
                if (x.id== tempArray1.forEach((doc)=>{
                
                  return doc.id})) {return x
                  
                }
             
              })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below:

```
const filteredArray = tempArray.filter(obj1 => tempArray1.some(obj2 => obj1.id === obj2.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

*First*:

If `london` is a string value, put it between **Quotation marks**.

*Second*:

Instead of using `forEach` you should use `filter` and `some` methods like below:

```
let newArray = tempArray.filter(x => tempArray1.some(doc => doc.id == x.id));
console.log(newArray)
```

The `some` method checks if any array elements pass a test (provided as a function).

The `filter` method creates a new array filled with elements that pass a test provided by a function.

You can check out the links: [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) and [some](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp).